# Why is the word 'driver' used in IT to describe software that helps hardware interface with the operating system?

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, operating-systems, terminology

What is the logic behind choosing the word driver to describe this kind of software and when did drivers start to be called this way ?

Comment: IIRC the term device driver was used in the 1960s with the IBM 360. On the Univac 1108 they were called device handlers. This would confirm the time period https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hNLKBQAAQBAJ&pg=SA80-PA4&lpg=SA80-PA4&dq=ibm+360+device+drivers&source=bl&ots=5odym7hvXk&sig=Xj6lWAn4qTkCC41YBzT9rJCtGtA&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjS6quYvf7QAhUKJMAKHRfnBWIQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=ibm%20360%20device%20drivers&f=false

Answer (score 1):

A driver is the software that drives the hardware. Without a software driver, the hardware does nothing (or something undefined).